# Dropping a streaming HTTP connection as soon as possible after losing connection

Tags: sockets, tcp, erlang, ip

So what we're trying to achieve is maintaining a vast number of concurrent connections from mobile devices to our Erlang HTTP server. Mobile devices of course can have have pretty intermittent connections, so we're looking to drop dead connections as soon as possible to avoid their overhead.

Now, I'm not sure at what level we should be detecting dead connections. TCP has keepalive packets, which require an ACK. So ideally we'd send a keepalive packet ever 15 seconds, and if we didn't receive the ACK within the next 15 seconds then we'd drop the connection. However, I've no idea if this is even possible in Erlang. Also, I think there's the possibility that some NATs, wi-fi routers and mobile networks are ACKing the keepalives for a certain amount of time, correct me if I'm wrong. Is that the case, and if so is there any TCP-level alternative way of doing 'heartbeats'?

We've also tried an application-level heartbeat - sending a \n down the HTTP stream. However, even with all applicable Erlang options set, including send_timeout, we're not getting any error for about 5 minutes under certain circumstances, such as, say, the mobile device straying too far from its wi-fi router.

How best can we implement a streaming HTTP connection that the server will drop as soon as possible after losing contact? Any help'd be much appreciated!

Comment: If it were not HTTP I'd simply recommend sending something from the client. Are you using a ready-made HTTP server or writing a custom one?

Comment: Can't you configure the socket keep alive timeout in the machine level?

Comment: @asaddude We've written our own HTTP server. If at all possible we'd like to stick to HTTP and not do any bi-directional stuff after the request.

Comment: @Isac Is that what's referred to on this page? http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

Comment: @Alec Yes, these are the parameters to configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isac's comment answered it for me - configuring the socket keep alive timeout at the machine level.

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html

Answer (score 2):

You can add a specific watchdog for HTTP connection. Watchdog will have configurable timeout that will be reset after each operation (read or write) on connection. And if there were no operations on socket within specified timeout - connection is closed.

This approach will eliminate the problem of stale connections (connections perfectly healthy but without any I/O activity). And if clients is out of coverage - connection will last only up to specified timeout. Also no keep-alive mechanism is needed when using watchdog approach.

The only drawback is that server will not detect broken connections immediately but will instead wait timeout specified in connection watchdog.